How can I simply repeatedly measure out small quantities of granular materials
I'm trying to measure out approximately 1 cubic centimeter of granular fertilizer onto 30,000 potted shrubs.
The grains of fertilizer are about he size of peppercorns.  They are moderately fragile. Think fragile peppercorns.
I initially considered a mechanism using gears.  Gear in cylinder, with a port on top and on the bottom.  -- easy to make with a 3d printer, but the shearing force where the gear leading edge hits the edge of the port with shatter grains.
What methods to companies use to handle granular materials that will work with a manual device?
Edit:  If under 10% break up it's no big deal.  If all of them are powdered, it's a very big deal.
Similarly consistency from one batch to the next a 10% slop is tolerable.
Custom coating on the prill:  Not happening.   30,000 pots at 1-5 g/pot is works out to less than a pallet of fert.  Fert companies do make time release prills that do this, but the times are too long for my growing season, and the cost is several times as high.

Rich's idea of a horizontal helix combined with Abel's idea of a soft material where the prill gets trapped between the moving and stationary bit has good possibilities.
Both of you could flesh this out as an answer for next searcher.

archimedes screw

How about an almost horizontal helical screw, where one turn delivers one cc? One turn for each pot.

You will have some destruction if they are fragile. Way to mitigate may be to only contact them with softer materials that have some give. It will reduce how accurate and consistent your dispenses are, but you might consider brushes or something similar.

how important is it actually that the grains stay intact?

@ratchetfreak It's plenty important. The solution is to specify a custom coating on the prill. The problem here is simply price. A small prill, greens-grade fertilizer with polymer coating will not have any problems, but they are more expensive than peppercorn fert.

On the other hand, it's only 1.3 bags, not like the truckloads we put down at the golf course. So yeah, work with the supplier to choose a prill that is best suited to the machinery. Here's one that can go down to 2cc - https://www.amleo.com/fertil-dispenseradjustable-granular-applicator/p/FTL5

Look at how some sugar dispensers work.

I'd look at powder tricklers. Or Maybe just a shallow ramp with a vibrator.

Following Abel's idea - If you go back to your original idea but alter the shape of the gear to have only one or two indents with spaces between. The cylinder is then opened up on the unload side and a stiff brush, or something similar is placed to level off the grains. This will prevent damage. The spaces on the gear allow only one scoop to fall at a time.  Here is a poor illustration of my idea.


Parhaps something like a squeegee, with a fiarly low attack angle so the prills are lifted up,
